# No module named 'pandas.core.apply'

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

While removing the zero and null values from pandas dataframe, the datatype of field gets changed.

```
df.info()
```

Output :

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10866 entries, 0 to 10865
Data columns (total 2 columns):
budget            10866 non-null int64
revenue           10866 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(2)
memory usage: 509.4+ KB
```

After running below code to remove zero and null values the datatype got changed.

```
temp_list_to_check_zero_values=['budget', 'revenue']
df[temp_list_to_check_zero_values] = df[temp_list_to_check_zero_values].replace(0, np.NAN)
df.info()
```

Output :

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3854 entries, 0 to 10848
Data columns (total 2 columns):
budget            3854 non-null float64
revenue           3854 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 210.8+ KB
```

To preserve the datatype, we used applymap

```
df[temp_list_to_check_zero_values] = df[temp_list_to_check_zero_values].applymap(np.int64)
```

But got error :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.core.apply'
```

Do we need to install any specific library for using applymap() ?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading your `pandas` should solve the issue.

Try `pip install pandas --upgrade`

Comment: Unfortunately, upgrading to latest version didn't helped.
Error : cannot import name 'AggFuncType' from 'pandas._typing' (C:\Users\Khilesh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\_typing.py)

Comment: Okay, lets try uninstalling first and then a fresh install for pandas
`pip uninstall pandas`

Also it could be an issue with the latest version. If the above does not work, try installing older versions.
`pip install pandas==1.1.5`